# Make less visible or completely hide ignore tagged questions

Tags: support

It seems a new change was made to SuperUser, where questions with tags on my ignore list are now almost as visible as regular questions. Only the title has a slightly different color.

This completely negates the purpose of using the ignore feature. How can I make these question less visible again, like it used to be, or otherwise completely filter them off the list?

See the image, there's nearly no distinction anymore between the middle and outer questions.

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming this is a network-wide change, in which case you'll probably have to bring this up on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com) (if it's not there already).

Comment: Posted there now. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381939/make-less-visible-or-completely-hide-ignore-tagged-questions . If a mod agrees that meta.stackexchange.com is the place where this should be asked, feel free to close/delete this one. Note, the image on the other answer is the same as here, so please don't delete the image.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381939/ignored-tags-no-longer-gray-out-the-questions